# Disable resizing a Form in VB6 while keeping the "Minimize" control

Tags: vb6

I’ve developed a VB6 application. Now I want to disabled resizing the form. I know there is a property `Border style`, which changes to `fixed single`, can do my work. But I want minimize button to my form. Minimize button is only in “Sizable” mode. I changed another property `MaxButton` to `false`. When I run my program, still I can re-size the form.

Please tell me how to disable resizing the Form.

Answer (score 11):

Can't you just set the "MinButton" property to true on fixed-single border form. I can in my version of VB6.

[image]